# How to get ObjectBox backlinks to save with Swift structs?

Tags: swift, objectbox

I made these 2 types.

```
struct FFF: Entity, Identifiable {
    let id: Id
    let name: String
    // objectbox: backlink = "f"
    var ns: ToMany<NNN>
}
struct NNN: Entity, Identifiable {
    let id: Id
    let name: String
    var f: ToOne<FFF>
}
```

Here is how I created two entities, established the relation using the `ToOne` property, and saved the change.

```
let path = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "/d"
let store = try Store(directoryPath: path)
let fffBox = store.box(for: FFF.self)
let nnnBox = store.box(for: NNN.self)
try fffBox.removeAll()
try nnnBox.removeAll()
let f0 = try fffBox.put(struct: FFF(id: 0, name: "X", ns: nil))
let n0 = try nnnBox.put(struct: NNN(id: 0, name: "Y", f: nil))
n0.f.target = f0
let n1 = try nnnBox.put(struct: n0)
let f1 = try fffBox.put(struct: f0)
print("f0 = \(f0)")
print("n0 = \(n0)")
print("f1 = \(f1)")
print("n1 = \(n1)")
let nstest = f1.ns
print("nstest = \(nstest)")
```

The output shows that the `ToMany` property is empty.

```
f0 = FFF(id: 1, name: "X", ns: ToMany<NNN>(unresolved))
n0 = NNN(id: 1, name: "Y", f: ToOne<FFF>(.stored(id: EntityId<FFF>(1), target: FFF(id: 1, name: "X", ns: ToMany<NNN>(unresolved)))))
f1 = FFF(id: 1, name: "X", ns: ToMany<NNN>(unresolved))
n1 = NNN(id: 1, name: "Y", f: ToOne<FFF>(.stored(id: EntityId<FFF>(1), target: FFF(id: 1, name: "X", ns: ToMany<NNN>(unresolved)))))
nstest = (unresolved)
```

If I flip the test, and set the `ToMany` property instead, then the `ToOne` property is nil.

What am I doing wrong? From what I can understand of [the docs](https://swift.objectbox.io/getting-started) and how to use structs instead of classes, I think I am calling the right funcs.

Comment: If I read this right (sorry, not an iOS dev) you need to read `f1` back from the database (e.g. `try fffBox.get(idOfF1)`) after putting the relation change, first?

Comment: @Uwe-ObjectBox The type returned from `get` also has `unresolved` for `ns`. I tried also calling `f1.ns.resolveFromDb()` and that shows empty array which proves the backlink is not working.

Comment: Just saw your issue. Was not aware that structs are immutable, so that's probably the primary reason (though not sure if the iOS library supports them in some way, but as ToOne/ToMany is typically lazy resolved that makes sense). I was also about to suggest to create an issue about this to continue from here, so there we go: https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-swift/issues/68

Comment: @Uwe-ObjectBox 68 is about needing better examples with Swift structs. https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-swift/issues/69 is about mutable structs not working either. Do you want a separate issue for immutable structs?